# Out of Memory (OOM) in android?

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, heap-memory

I'm struggling with **OOM Error** while playing videos. I have more than 10 videos in `raw` folder. (because Client needs). while playing this Videos this OOM occurs.

> I'm using Native Video View here

I'm applying these Solutions :

- `android:largeHeap="true"`
- `System.gc();`
- `mp.release();` MediaPlayer.release();

Thanks for your response.

Comment: Please put your related code and the error log so anyone can see and try to help you.

Comment: Actually i don't know  which code Affects the memory.